# DotNet appears to allow two processes to open the same port?

Tags: .net, linux, sockets, docker, .net-core

I'm running a DotNet service on a Docker `centos:7` container and I'm running into issues with the code I was given running differently under a `dotnet publish` vs a `dotnet run` situation.

I currently have dotnet service running that listens on port `3480`.  It appears the dotnet code I'm running also attempts to instantiate a `TcpListener` on the same port.

In `dotnet run` mode it *appears* to let this happen, where as in publish I get an `address in use` error.

So before I run my code I have this `net stat -lntp`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3840            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5017/dotnet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

where **pid 5017** my service is listening on the TCP port

After I start up my code things look like this:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        1      0 0.0.0.0:3840            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5247/dotnet
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:4000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5247/dotnet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

**PID 5247** seems to have taken over??

Then when I terminate the code we go back to this state:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3840            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5017/dotnet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

The only difference I can come up with is when I do a `ps -eo pid, command` I get this:

```
 5017 /usr/bin/dotnet /usr/share/my-agent/My.Agent.Linux.dll
 5247 dotnet exec /devel/SandBox/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/ServerSandbox.dll
```

If I run the published version `dotnet publish -o publish -r linux-x64 -c Debug` I get this:

```
 5017 /usr/bin/dotnet /usr/share/my-agent/My.Agent.Linux.dll
 8405 ./publish/My.ServerSandbox
```

And as the code crashes the `PID` controlling port `4080` remains the same.

My though process is that the `DotNet Runtime` somehow is actually managing the ports itself - which is why it will allow the same port to be open twice, where as when I publish my code out I'm using an embedded runtime and thus we get caught doing something that shouldn't happen.

Has anybody seen this behavior before?  I've been running in circles as to why I couldn't get the published version working and after digging down I'm of the opinion its the run version that shouldn't be working.

Thanks for any advice/help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research it did appear our server was doing exactly what we suspected.  We changed our source code to not open the same port twice and everything fell into step.  As to why this was even possible I'm still confused - so if you are running into a similar situation hopefully this question can offer you some solace.

Comment: .NET can't do something the OS doesn't allow. In one case though you seem to be running *debug* code - `/devel/SandBox/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/ServerSandbox.dll`. `publish` builds a Release version before packaging it.